# How to return true after finding every nth element for all elements

Tags: python, arrays, return, iteration

I'm trying to get every nth element in an array, but the function stops iterating due to the return true statement.

Here is my code:

```python
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def get_nth(n, array):
    iterable_found = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(i)

        if i == (iterable_found + n):
            iterable_found += n
            
            return True
            
    return False


>>> print(get_nth(5, numbers))
0
1
2
3
4
5
True
```

But I want it so it goes through the rest of the array and returns true for 10 and 15. I plan on running this function through a while loop so I can actively get every nth element that is added. Thank you for any help.

Minimal example:

Csv file with numbers being streamed to it from websocket

```
1
2
3
...
```

function call

```
import np
array = np.genfromtxt('feed.csv', delimiter = ',')

# loop for checking

while True:
    print(get_nth(5, array))
```

Comment: why don't you print ```True``` instead of returning it. Also, I guess you want ```print(array[i])``` instead of ```print(i)```.

Comment: What's your end goal? It sounds like you want `numbers[n-1::n]` ultimately, but that's not what the code does at all.

Comment: @wjandrea I plan on reading from an active file that gets appended numbers and I need to know if there has been an nth element.

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin I need the function to return a boolean value. Eg if there has been an nth element, then do something

Comment: In that case you can use ```yield``` instead of ```return```.

Comment: Also, just to make it more clear, can you please provide a sample, input and output.

Comment: @testerboy22 Oh, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) then. Files are not arrays, and you can't solve that problem the same way. Please ask about the *actual* problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @wjandrea Well, I'm appending data from a csv file to an array, so technically the only thing different would be the numbers. I'm looping through the array using a while loop and checking for every nth element.

Comment: @testerboy22 OK, so show us the while loop and the read from the file. See [mre] for tips.

Comment: @testerboy22 OK, I'm looking at it but I'm not sure I'm following. That code only reads the file once. Is that intentional? And what output do you want to get? `True` printed 3 times?

Comment: Also, beside the point, but I think you meant `import numpy as np`

Comment: @wjandrea True printed after every nth interval I specify in the function.

Comment: A function only returns once per time that it is called. A function, conceptually, represents a calculation, and what is `return`ed is the result of that calculation. I can't understand what you mean by "getting" an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps , this works by returning the last position the function left off when returning and picks up from there when it called again with the last position.

```
import random

numbers = [3, 7, 3, 111, 222, 333, 4444, 555, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]


def get_nth(n, array, startPos):
    for x in range(startPos, len(array)):
        print(array[x])
        if (array[x] % n) == 0:
            return True, x
    return False


pos = 0
while True:
    if pos < len(numbers):
        result, pos = get_nth(3, numbers, pos)
        print(result)
        pos += 1

    # Works when adding numbers into the numbers list in the loop
    # or your case your websocket
    numbers.append(random.randint(0, 999))
```

Output

```
8
True
983
615
True
479
735
True
155
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to work. But may I ask why you return false twice? I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: Redundant will edit the answer , no problem :)

Comment: I originally added it for when the function would return a False and it would try to unpack it at " "result, pos = get_nth(3, numbers, pos)"" and an error would show

Comment: Oh, and by the way, whenever it there's an integer that isn't a multiple of n at the end of the array it errors. Eg numbers = [..., 13,  14] returns TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Comment: then maybe keep the False,False

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword stops the function once it is executed. To avoid this you can just replace the `return` keyword with `yield`. It would allow you to store all the values you want to return into something similar to a list.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

def get_nth(n, array):
    iterable_found = 0

    if len(array) >= n:
      for i in range(len(array) + 1):
          print(i)
          if i == (iterable_found + n):
              iterable_found += n
              yield (True, i)
    else:
      yield False

list(get_nth(5, numbers))
```

Answer (score -1):

the ***return*** keyword acts as the end of the function, thus according to your requirements, you shouldn't return anything. Instead, you can just create an empty array and add the numbers where there is an iterable found

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
iterable_numbers = []

def get_nth(n, array):
    iterable_found = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        print(i)

        if i == (iterable_found + n):
            iterable_found += n
            
            iterable_numbers.append(i)
```

Comment: Why is `iterable_numbers` created outside the function? It should be inside the function and get returned at the end. Although, maybe it'd be better to use a generator instead.